# Stuck at BusyBox error after trying to fix other errors

Tags: 15.04, busybox

I get stuck at the `busybox` menu after a while and I don't know what to do.

1. I installed Ubuntu on my laptop, and after I put it to sleep I came to it the next day and it was on a black screen.
2. After holding down the power button - and restarting - I got stuck in a login loop.
3. Upon trying to fix the login loop issue ([Steps from here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/223501/ubuntu-gets-stuck-in-a-login-loop)), the laptop gets to the `busybox` menu.

It won't allow me to plug in the USB I originally installed it from.

EDIT: Recreated the original USB and making some progress, however this question may become still open if the issue repeats (as it probably will).

EDIT2: Re-ran installer, ubuntu didn't install (errno 30) and USB is again not booting into ubuntu, with "error: no such partition" and grub rescue.

Comment: *"upon trying to fix"*... how? can you describe the steps you took?

Comment: First things first, have you tried to boot a live DVD and run a fsck on all of your partitions?

Comment: @steeldriver https://askubuntu.com/questions/223501/ubuntu-gets-stuck-in-a-login-loop I took the steps in that question.

Comment: @FuzzyToothpaste That's the problem - I don't seem to be able to get back into that USB I created.

Answer (score 0):

I know the guidelines don't like me doing this, but I can't comment:

Have you tried holding down one of the common BIOS keys during boot?

Comment: Laptop has a little button on the side you have to press in (takes you to BIOS menu, boot menu etc.) - after remaking the USB, I got into ubuntu, but the installer yet again broke, and after a reboot, it appears the USB has literally deleted itself.

Comment: @ArronFaulkner Okay then.... Try and make the USB stick on a separate computer, and boot from that, **and DO NOT BOOT INTO THE EXISTING UBUNTU!** It seems like the ubuntu install is very broken.  Try running GParted and tell me what your main Ubuntu partition type is. Don't do anything else on your computer after that, only use other computers

Comment: I got a screen shot of gparted: http://i.imgur.com/P9KmSmW.png - that's the /dev/sda, This laptop also has a /dev/sdb, and ubuntu seems to keep trying to use it to install on even though it has gone corrupt (it seems). Everytime I choose it to install on /dev/sda but it seems like it tried to install on /dev/sdb. /dev/sda partition is msdos and /dev/sdb is partitioned as mac for some weird  reason.

Comment: That looks like some pretty nasty file system corruption to me. You can't fix it without booting into a live system, so look into the problem with your live USB deleting itself, or just make a CD. Maybe you should try making the live USB with UNetbootin, I've had pretty good results with that.

Comment: @ArronFaulkner Boot into the live USB/CD and open a terminal: `sudo -i`       
then
`fsck.ext4 -p -y -v /dev/sda1` And repeat the `fsck` one but with sda3. This will attempt to fix any corruption in your partitions (AFAIK).

Comment: @FireFaced I recieved an error:

`fsck.ext4: Attempt to read block from filesystem resulted in short read while trying to open /dev/sda1. Could this be a zero-length partition?`

Comment: @ArronFaulkner Oh, try sda5 and sda3